# java, trying to add a picture to JFrame

Tags: java, image, jframe

I'm trying to make a simple game. I can't figure out how to add an image to a `JFrame`.

Some info: I'm on a mac OS X. I am programing in Java.

The question: how do I add an image to a `JFrame` in a way to be able to move it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create JFrame
- create JPanel and add it to JFrame
- in paint method from your JPanel add [Graphics.drawImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) method to display image in x, y position

edited:

Panel example:

```
public class ImageInPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;
    private int x;
    private int y;    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but I'm doing something wrong. this is my code so far. wind = new JFrame("header");wind.setSize(1000, 750);Image pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("image.png");JPanel jp = new JPanel();wind.add(jp);jp.paint(Graphics.drawImage(pic,10,0,jp));

Comment: Ok, I've added example. Set all value (x, y, image) and then call repaint on ImageInPanel, should works.

Comment: In `JPanel`, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)`!

Comment: yeah, paintComponent is another solution but the idea is the same

Answer (score 1):

Create a JLabel with an ImageIcon. Then you can move the image around the frame by using:

```
label.setLocation(...);
```